# Link click overriding in a webBrowser control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am using Virtual Studio Community in C# (.Net 4.5).
I have a simple form, which contains one button and one webBrowser control.
When I click the button, I make the webBrowser navigate to google.com.
Then, when the page is loaded, I try to override the linkClick events as I saw in a solution I read on this site (stackoverflow) earlier.
But then, when I click on a link on the loaded page, it says the navigation was cancelled, but it navigates anyways.
What am I doing wrong?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com/");
    }

    private bool bCancel = false;

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < webBrowser1.Document.Links.Count; i++)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.Links[i].Click += new HtmlElementEventHandler(this.LinkClick);
        }
    }
    private void LinkClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        bCancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Link Was Clicked Navigation was Cancelled");
    }
    private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bCancel == true)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            bCancel = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `WebBrowserControl.Navigating` event to the handler you've written; having the handler's name matching the control *underscore* event name isn't enough.

So you can do this in the `Form1`'s constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    webBrowser1.Navigating += new WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler(webBrowser1_Navigating);
}
```

Better yet, add a `Load` event and do the same there. Check out the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowsernavigatingeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx#Properties) on the subject.

Comment: I added the line of code you provided in the constructor, as you mentioned, same result, the webBrowser loads the google page, I click on a link, a MessageBox says navigation was cancelled, but it navigates anyways.